# Hibernate not saving time-stamp fields

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I am working on some project i am using Spring/Hibernate to create my application (Hibernate 4.3.6) // Spring (4.3.0) the problem with me is when i store a date field it get stored as "0000-00-00 00:00:00" i have tried the following:

1-

`@Column
private Timestamp registerationDate;`

2-

```
@Column
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Timestamp registerationDate;
```

3-

```
private Date registerationDate;
```

4-

```
@Column
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date registerationDate;
```

All my tests gave the same result.
I am using MySQL as my database

Comment: did you specify @Column name in entity? i am asking it because i cannt see in your posted bit code.

Comment: I have tried every single optino with column and without column and got the same result

Comment: Have you tried to put just annotation column above the date variable? Like 

`@Column(name = "date_field")
private Date createDttm;`

Comment: @LorekBryanson i haven't add "name" property, and i am sure that this property is an optional one

Comment: @BahaaKhateib the `@Column(column_name)` I was suggesting is actually pointing to your database's date column

Answer (score 0):

try with java.util.Date as your timestamp type. also initialize it in setter method or somewhere before persisting.

Comment: I have done that, also i have printed the object before persisting to make sure that i have the correct date, same results

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, i just update MySQL connector dependency, now i am using the latest version "5.1.44" which solved the issue, i used Date Field as is without using temporal and it worked successfully